# Web Form displaying time when SQL only stores date

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a C# Web Form that displays results from a SELECT statement into a Gridview. I have a column in SQL called Start_Date that stores as date. In SQL, it looks like this

```
2017-10-31
```

However, when I bind my grid, I always get

```
10/31/2017 12:00:00 AM
```

My SELECT statement looks like this

```
SELECT Start_Date FROM Table WHERE Start_Date > GETDATE()
```

I even tried casting `Start_Date` as date but it still displays time. Where would that time be coming from if the SQL column is not storing it?

My bind is rather simple as well.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.CommandType = commandType;

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
sda.Fill(dt);
gvPending.DataSource = dt;
gvPending.DataBind();
```

Comment: [All of the SQL Server date types map to a DateTime in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings). And DateTime has a time component. You don't have to display it: just modify your GridView to display the date in a different format.

Comment: `2017-10-31` <=> `2017-10-31 00:00:00` <=> `10/31/2017 12:00:00 AM` Simply it is presentation matter.

Comment: thanks guys.  Thought the bound field would just display what SQL told it to display.  didn't realize it would take C#'s default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Gridview, you can format your datetime:

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="Your_Date_Column" dataformatstring="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
```

Or you can create a new property in your class where you format the datetime field as required, then bind that property to the column in the grid.

Otherwise the time will show up once you retrieve the value directly from SQL and bind it.

Comment: Welcome! Please, accept it as an answer if worked for you so it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if you are using Template Field:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start_Date">
    <ItemTemplate>                           
        <asp:Label ID="lblStart_Date" runat="server" Font-Size="10px" CssClass="ControlStyleUpperCase" 
Text='<%# Bind("Start_Date","{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:tt}") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```